# Why is my unfinished javascript game crashing after the 3rd death?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Commented because does not work in Sandbox
// window.localStorage; //Ignore this line

// Where all my variables have been assigned

var c = document.getElementById("GameScreen");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var charY = 220;
const gravity = 10;
var score = 0;
var time = 0;
var speed = 5;
var cloneID = 0;
var clonePos = [600];
var clonePoints = [0];
var animationBounce = 0;
var jump = 10;
var charDead = 0;
var dataCharY = [];
var dataDisObst = [];
var disObst = 1000;
var lowestLoopDis;
var jumpFactor = 0;
var disDeath;
var AIgames = 1;
var bestScoreAI = 0;

ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);

// Was going to use this for background trees but haven't done it yet

new obj(50, 50, 30, 30);

// Runs most functions

function runAll() {
  if (charDead == 0) {
    clearAll(); //This function runs most of the code
    updateChar();
    createGround();
    updateObj();
    groundDetect();
    updateScore();
    hitDetect();
    addData();
    testBetterAI();
    getDisObst();
    jumpAI();
    removeUnusedObst();
  }
}

// Was going to use this for trees but haven't yet

function obj(x, y, width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.arc(-293, 150, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  this.cloneID = cloneID;
}

new obj(-293, 212, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

// Creates the floor (IKR)

function createGround() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(-635, 250, c.width, 50);
}

// Creates the character every milisecond (or 10, I can't remember)

function updateChar() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(-300, charY - animationBounce, 15, 30);
  ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(-293, charY - animationBounce - 15, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Removes everything in order to be redrawn in new position

function clearAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(-700, -700, 2000, 2000);
}

// Redraws every square / object

function updateObj() {
  for (var i = 0; i != clonePos.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(clonePos[i], 220, 30, 30);
  }
}

// Creates new square (I also decided to rename them half way through with obstacle instead of object)

function createObst() {
  clonePos.push(600);
  cloneID++;
}

// Changes the squares / obstacles position relative to the movement

function moveObst() {
  for (var ii = 0; ii != clonePos.length; ii++) {
    clonePos[ii] -= speed;
  }
}

// Tests to see if the character is on the ground

function groundDetect() {
  if (charY > 220) {
    charY = 220;
  }
}

// Makes gravity actually work

function charGravity() {
  if (charY < 220) {
    charY += gravity;
  }
}

// Updates the score counter text

function updateScore() {
  document.getElementById("scoreText").innerHTML = score;
}

// Gives the character a little bounce when moving

function charBounce() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 200);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 300);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 400);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 600);
}

// Makes the character jump

function charJump() {
  if (charY == 220) {
    jump = 4;

    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 20);
    jump = 8;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 40);
    jump = 12;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 60);
    jump = 16;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 80);
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 120);
  }
}

// Detects when the character has a hit a square

function hitDetect() {
  for (var iB = 0; iB != clonePos.length; iB++) {
    if (clonePos[iB] > -320 && clonePos[iB] < -280 && charY > 200) {
      charDied();
    }
  }
}

// Runs when character dies

function charDied() {
  disDeath = disObst;
  charDead = 1;

  charRevive();

  testBetterAI();

  decideAdjustments();
}

// Adds score very interval

function addingScore() {
  if (charDead == 0) {
    score += 100;
  }
}

// Adds to an array that I will use later

function addData() {
  dataCharY.push(charY);
  dataDisObst.push(disObst);
}

// Test to see if one of my AI's (which hasn't been made yet) scores is better than the previous best

function testBetterAI() {
  // Commented because does not work in Sandbox
  // if (score > localStorage.getItem("bestScore")) {
  // }
}

// Calculates the distance to the nearest square / obstacle

function getDisObst() {
  lowestLoopDis = 1000;

  for (var iiA = 0; iiA != clonePos.length; iiA++) {
    if (clonePos[iiA] > -320) {
      if (clonePos[iiA] > 0) {
        if (Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]) < lowestLoopDis) {
          lowestLoopDis = Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]);
        }
      } else {
        if (Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]) < lowestLoopDis) {
          lowestLoopDis = Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (lowestLoopDis < disObst) {
    disObst = lowestLoopDis;
  }
}

// Increments the speed of the obstacles / squares and the character

function addSpeed() {
  if (speed < 25) {
    speed++;
  }
}

// Restarts the game

function charRevive() {
  clonePos = [600];
  charDead = 0;
  score = 0;
  time = 0;
  speed = 5;
  AIgames++;
}

// I accidently did this twice, whoops

function testBetterAI() {
  if (score > bestScoreAI) {
    bestScoreAI = score;
  }
}

// Makes the unfinished AI jump when it wants to

function jumpAI() {
  if (disObst <= disDeath + jumpFactor) {
    charJump();
  }
}

// What changes need to be made in order to improve the AI

function decideAdjustments() {
  jumpFactor += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;

  if (jumpFactor < 0) {
    jumpFactor = 0;
  }
}

// Removing blocks that are off the screen

function removeUnusedObst() {
  if (clonePos[0] < -650) {
    clonePos.shift();
  }
}

// Intervals here

setInterval(function() {
  time++;
}, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
  runAll();
}, 10);
setInterval(function() {
  moveObst();
}, 50);
setInterval(function() {
  charGravity();
}, 25);
setInterval(function() {
  createObst();
}, 3000);
setInterval(function() {
  charBounce();
}, 650);
setInterval(function() {
  addingScore();
}, 3500);
setInterval(function() {
  addSpeed();
}, 25000);
```

```css
#GameScreen {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

#scoreText {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scoreText"></div>
<canvas id="GameScreen" width="1270px" height="550px"></canvas>
```

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you put all the code in a codepen or codesandbox and included the additional information as comments.

Comment: @Jawi We prefer the code here in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Please indent your code so it's more readable.

Comment: @blex That note doesn't really belong in the question, does it?

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to make sure the OP would see it and not clutter the comments. @opetch18 : I edited your question to make your code runnable right here on Stack Overflow. In that process, I had to comment both lines using `localStorage`, which throws an error as it is blocked. Since they are not used yet, it's not important. But be sure to uncomment them afterwards. On the first line, and in the `testBetterAI` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What happens**

In your `hitDetect` function:

```
function hitDetect() {
  for (var iB = 0; iB != clonePos.length; iB++) {
    if (clonePos[iB] > -320 && clonePos[iB] < -280 && charY > 200) {
      charDied();
    }
  }
}
```

You loop over the `clonePos` array, until `iB` is equal to the length of that array. If a condition is met (collision), you execute `charDied`, which, in turn, executes `charRevive`:

```
function charRevive() {
  clonePos = [600];
  // ...
}
```

Meanwhile, the `hitDetect` loop continues. And at one point *(seemingly when you start to increase the speed)*, it happens that `iB` is now above `1`, which is the new length of `clonePos`. Now, what happens? Well, you are trapped in an infinite loop:

[image]

**Lesson to be learned**

If you're looping on an Array which can mutate during the loop (and change its length), **never** use this type of condition:

```
i != myArr.length
```

Always prefer a stricter condition if you want your loop to end at some point:

```
i < myArr.length
```

And, even better, if looping makes no sense after a condition is met, end this loop by returning. eg:

```
function hitDetect() {
  for (var iB = 0; iB < clonePos.length; iB++) {
    if (clonePos[iB] > -320 && clonePos[iB] < -280 && charY > 200) {
      return charDied();
      // Alternatively, if there is other stuff to do after the loop, you can use:
      // break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Fixed code**

```js
// Commented because does not work in Sandbox
// window.localStorage; //Ignore this line

// Where all my variables have been assigned

var c = document.getElementById("GameScreen");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var charY = 220;
const gravity = 10;
var score = 0;
var time = 0;
var speed = 5;
var cloneID = 0;
var clonePos = [600];
var clonePoints = [0];
var animationBounce = 0;
var jump = 10;
var charDead = 0;
var dataCharY = [];
var dataDisObst = [];
var disObst = 1000;
var lowestLoopDis;
var jumpFactor = 0;
var disDeath;
var AIgames = 1;
var bestScoreAI = 0;

ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);

// Was going to use this for background trees but haven't done it yet

new obj(50, 50, 30, 30);

// Runs most functions

function runAll() {
  if (charDead == 0) {
    clearAll(); //This function runs most of the code
    updateChar();
    createGround();
    updateObj();
    groundDetect();
    updateScore();
    hitDetect();
    addData();
    testBetterAI();
    getDisObst();
    jumpAI();
    removeUnusedObst();
  }
}

// Was going to use this for trees but haven't yet

function obj(x, y, width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.arc(-293, 150, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  this.cloneID = cloneID;
}

new obj(-293, 212, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

// Creates the floor (IKR)

function createGround() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(-635, 250, c.width, 50);
}

// Creates the character every milisecond (or 10, I can't remember)

function updateChar() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(-300, charY - animationBounce, 15, 30);
  ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(-293, charY - animationBounce - 15, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Removes everything in order to be redrawn in new position

function clearAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(-700, -700, 2000, 2000);
}

// Redraws every square / object

function updateObj() {
  for (var i = 0; i < clonePos.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(clonePos[i], 220, 30, 30);
  }
}

// Creates new square (I also decided to rename them half way through with obstacle instead of object)

function createObst() {
  clonePos.push(600);
  cloneID++;
}

// Changes the squares / obstacles position relative to the movement

function moveObst() {
  for (var ii = 0; ii < clonePos.length; ii++) {
    clonePos[ii] -= speed;
  }
}

// Tests to see if the character is on the ground

function groundDetect() {
  if (charY > 220) {
    charY = 220;
  }
}

// Makes gravity actually work

function charGravity() {
  if (charY < 220) {
    charY += gravity;
  }
}

// Updates the score counter text

function updateScore() {
  document.getElementById("scoreText").innerHTML = score;
}

// Gives the character a little bounce when moving

function charBounce() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 200);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce++;
  }, 300);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 400);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationBounce--;
  }, 600);
}

// Makes the character jump

function charJump() {
  if (charY == 220) {
    jump = 4;

    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 20);
    jump = 8;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 40);
    jump = 12;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 60);
    jump = 16;
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 80);
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      charY -= jump;
    }, 120);
  }
}

// Detects when the character has a hit a square

function hitDetect() {
  for (var iB = 0; iB < clonePos.length; iB++) {
    if (clonePos[iB] > -320 && clonePos[iB] < -280 && charY > 200) {
      return charDied();
    }
  }
}

// Runs when character dies

function charDied() {
  disDeath = disObst;
  charDead = 1;

  charRevive();

  testBetterAI();

  decideAdjustments();
}

// Adds score very interval

function addingScore() {
  if (charDead == 0) {
    score += 100;
  }
}

// Adds to an array that I will use later

function addData() {
  dataCharY.push(charY);
  dataDisObst.push(disObst);
}

// Test to see if one of my AI's (which hasn't been made yet) scores is better than the previous best

function testBetterAI() {
  // Commented because does not work in Sandbox
  // if (score > localStorage.getItem("bestScore")) {
  // }
}

// Calculates the distance to the nearest square / obstacle

function getDisObst() {
  lowestLoopDis = 1000;

  for (var iiA = 0; iiA < clonePos.length; iiA++) {
    if (clonePos[iiA] > -320) {
      if (clonePos[iiA] > 0) {
        if (Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]) < lowestLoopDis) {
          lowestLoopDis = Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]);
        }
      } else {
        if (Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]) < lowestLoopDis) {
          lowestLoopDis = Math.abs(clonePos[iiA]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (lowestLoopDis < disObst) {
    disObst = lowestLoopDis;
  }
}

// Increments the speed of the obstacles / squares and the character

function addSpeed() {
  if (speed < 25) {
    speed++;
  }
}

// Restarts the game

function charRevive() {
  clonePos = [600];
  charDead = 0;
  score = 0;
  time = 0;
  speed = 5;
  AIgames++;
}

// I accidently did this twice, whoops

function testBetterAI() {
  if (score > bestScoreAI) {
    bestScoreAI = score;
  }
}

// Makes the unfinished AI jump when it wants to

function jumpAI() {
  if (disObst <= disDeath + jumpFactor) {
    charJump();
  }
}

// What changes need to be made in order to improve the AI

function decideAdjustments() {
  jumpFactor += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;

  if (jumpFactor < 0) {
    jumpFactor = 0;
  }
}

// Removing blocks that are off the screen

function removeUnusedObst() {
  if (clonePos[0] < -650) {
    clonePos.shift();
  }
}

// Intervals here

setInterval(function() {
  time++;
}, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
  runAll();
}, 10);
setInterval(function() {
  moveObst();
}, 50);
setInterval(function() {
  charGravity();
}, 25);
setInterval(function() {
  createObst();
}, 3000);
setInterval(function() {
  charBounce();
}, 650);
setInterval(function() {
  addingScore();
}, 3500);
setInterval(function() {
  addSpeed();
}, 25000);
```

```css
body { text-align: center; }
#GameScreen {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  width: 350px; height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scoreText"></div>
<canvas id="GameScreen" width="1270px" height="550px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help