# Javascript stop countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a countdown in js and I can't add a trick I would like.

When the counting ends, it does not stop. Negative numbers start and instead I would like it to stop at 0 once the time has expired. How can I?

```
  var counter = null;

  window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

  function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

  function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

    return val;
  }

  function getLocalStorage(key) {
    return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
  }

  function timer() {
    count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
    if (count == -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = hours +  " ore "  + minutes +  " min "   + seconds +  "  sec";
  }
```

Comment: Is `clearInterval` actually executed?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Checkk/apd3h79o/2/?fbclid=IwAR1rV3GOUIplVmyfZUI_YZ5SdPRFZP3HhYhvrXRCiZ41KzEhrSPn0-H1Zo8

Comment: Have you tried checking for `count < 0` instead of `count == -1`? It might be a rounding error with floating-point values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you were putting `count` with `-1` value in `LocalStorage`.

```
count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
```

And after page reload you kept subtracting `1` from `-1` and you got `-2`, which your condition `count == -1` couldn't catch. Solution is to put next count value in `LocalStorage` after you check if need to continue your timer or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  let count = 0;
  let counter = null;

  window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

  function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    count = Number(getLocalStorage('count')) || 5;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

  function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
     window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

    return val;
  }

  function getLocalStorage(key) {
    return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
  }

  function timer() {
    const nextCount = count - 1
    if (nextCount < 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }
    count = setLocalStorage('count', nextCount);

    const seconds = count % 60;
    let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours +  " ore "  + minutes +  " min "   + seconds +  "  sec";
  }
 </script>

<div id="timer"></div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You're welcome, and don't forget to upvote & accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if (count == -1) {
  clearInterval(counter);
  return;
}
```

To this:

```
if (count < 0) {
  clearInterval(counter);
  localStorage.removeItem('count');
  return;
}
```

Always make your conditions as strict as you can, or [you will run into trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60309627/1913729). You don't actually care that it's equal to `-1`. You care that it's below `0`.

In your original code, it stops fine when the page is loaded without localStorage. But at the end, you set the localStorage to `-1`. When you refresh, you set it to `-2` (`count - 1`) and start the counter going into the negatives. Your condition is never checked against that `-1` value which was stored.